# Nodejs request 'proxy' option is not routing request through defined host

Tags: node.js, proxy, request, fiddler, charles-proxy

I am having difficulty viewing the information exchanged between a Node js application and an API.

The developers are using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. Looking at the readme there is an option called 'proxy':

```
proxy - An HTTP proxy to be used. Supports proxy Auth with Basic Auth, identical to support for the url parameter (by embedding the auth info in the uri)
```

However when I add in the proxy as an option it seems to be discarded because while the request is passed to the server I see no information in my http proxy (Charles or Fiddler)

The options I am using are:

```
exports.defaultOptions = function(){
  return {
    host: config.apiHost, // API url to connect too
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    method: 'POST', // Default method
    port: config.apiPort, // API port number to connect too
    proxy: 'http://192.168.2.183:8888'
  };
};
```

I have tried other methods of debugging the traffic (tunneling agents, proxychains) but these all seem to result in a CONNECT method rather than a GET or a POST.

If anyone has any experience of using the proxy option, or indeed if I have fundamentally misunderstood the implementation or use of the proxy option, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'url' instead of 'host'.  I'm assuming from the inline comment, it is a full url to the endpoint of the api.

```
exports.defaultOptions = function(){
  return {
    url: config.apiHost, // API url to connect too
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    method: 'POST', // Default method
    port: config.apiPort, // API port number to connect too
    proxy: 'http://192.168.2.183:8888'
  };
};
```

From [docs](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback) :
uri || url - fully qualified uri or a parsed url object from